# Blueprint property-placeholder provider

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

In OSGi blueprint I can get params from property-placeholder
`<cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="id" update-strategy="reload"/>.` But, these params will be loaded from .cfg. I need to load params from DataBase, can I set params provider for property-placeholder?

Answer (score 0):

The property-placeholder 
The cm:property-placeholder can only feed properties from config admin. So there is no simple soltuion by just configuring some xml.

There are three ways to achieve this:

1. You can write a ConfigAdmin backend that retrieves configs from a database.
2. You can write your own blueprint namespace that implements an element like the property-placeholder element and retrieves the configs from the database.
3. A simpler solution would be to install a bundle in your runtime that reads the database and uses the ConfigurationAdmin service to create configs according to the database contents.

So I would opt for the 3rd solution. A good side effect of it is that once you have written the configs there is no outage if the database goes down.